# How to stop a task of FluentScheduler?

Tags: c#, wpf, scheduler, fluentscheduler

I am using `FluentScheduler`, and have a Registry class,

```
public class UnreadAlertRegistry : Registry
{
  public UnreadAlertRegistry(int minute, string user, bool? type)
    {

        var alertAction = new Action(() =>
          {
            // show message box 
          }
       Schedule(alertAction).ToRunEvery(minute).Minutes();
     }
  }
```

and in app, i Initialize it.

```
alert = new UnreadAlertRegistry(5, _dashboardUser, false);
TaskManager.Initialize(alert);
```

it is run every 5 minute.

I want to stop this. How do i stop this Scheduler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I set a Name for schedule.

```
Schedule(alertAction).WithName("UnreadAlertRegistry").ToRunEvery(minute).Minutes();
```

and for stop it , use `RemoveTask`

```
TaskManager.RemoveTask("UnreadAlertRegistry");
```

Comment: for remove, it seems we need to use JobManager.RemoveJob(''NAME'')

Comment: I confirm that it is now `JobManager.RemoveJob("UnreadAlertRegistry");`